# loops for prevent duplicate input to an array

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

So, for our c# class we have to create an array of 5 objects, that have 4 properties

an int for job number
a string for job name
a string for job description
a double for expected hours of the job.

I need in my loop a way to prevent the user from entering a duplicate job number: here is my code so far. This code works, but will allow duplicate job numbers;

```
namespace JobDemo2
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Job[] jobbies = new Job[5];
        int x;
        int jobNum;
        string customerName;
        string description;
        double hours;
        const double RATE = 45.00;

        for (x = 0; x < jobbies.Length; ++x)// creates array
        {
            GetJobData(out jobNum, out customerName, out description, out hours, jobbies);
            jobbies[x] = new Job(jobNum, customerName, description, hours);            
        }

        //Array.Sort(jobbies);
        Console.WriteLine("The jobs, sorted, are: ");
        for (x = 0; x < jobbies.Length; ++x) // prints the array values
        {
            DisplayJobs(jobbies[x]); 
        }

        double totalRevenue = (jobbies[0].Hours + jobbies[1].Hours + 
                 jobbies[2].Hours + jobbies[3].Hours + jobbies[4].Hours) * RATE;
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("The total revenue projected is {0}", totalRevenue);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void GetJobData(out int jobNum, 
         out string customerName, out string description, out double hours, 
         Job[] jobbies)
    {                   
        string inString;

        Console.Write("Please enter a job number >> ");
        inString = Console.ReadLine();
        int.TryParse(inString, out jobNum);

        Console.Write("Please enter the customer's name for this job >> ");
        customerName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Please enter the job's description >> ");
        description = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Please enter the projected hours for the job >> ");
        inString = Console.ReadLine();
        double.TryParse(inString, out hours);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    static void DisplayJobs(Job jobbies)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0, 5} {1, -10} {2, 6} {3, 8}", 
          jobbies.JobNumber, jobbies.Customer, jobbies.Description, jobbies.Hours);
    }
}

class Job //object
{
    private double hours;
    private double price;
    public const double RATE = 45.00;
    public Job(int num, string cust, string desc, double hrs)
    {
        JobNumber = num;
        Customer = cust;
        Description = desc;
        Hours = hrs;
    }
    public int JobNumber { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Hours
    {
        get
        {
            return hours;
        }
        set
        {
            hours = value;
            price = hours * RATE;
        }
    }
    public double Price
    {
        get
        {
            return price;
        }
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return (GetType() + " " + JobNumber + " " + Customer + " " +
           Description + " " + Hours + " hours @" + RATE.ToString("C") +
           " per hour. Total price is " + Price.ToString("C"));
    }
    public override bool Equals(Object e)
    {
        bool equal;
        Job temp = (Job)e;
        if (JobNumber == temp.JobNumber)
            equal = true;
        else
            equal = false;
        return equal;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return JobNumber;
    }
}
}
```

the teacher is suggesting to the class that we ad another for loop here that compares the objects. What would that for loop look like?

Here is her email:

> help for the looping create a boolean variable.
>   for loop through your array to ask the user to enter info and set your bool variable to true.
>
> another for loop inside to call the equals method in the class that will compare the job just entered to each object in In the array. This is where most are messing up because you must compare objects to objects and not an interger for job number to an entire object.  if the objects equal set the bool to false.
>
> while the bool is false you want to tell them they entered a wrong number and to enter again.  Set the bool to true in here and go the same for loop to compare again. as long as the number stays false the user will be stuck in this while loop. when they enter a correct number it will break out.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What an error do you get when calling `Equals`?

Comment: So, ive tried creating a for loop that looks like this;<br/>

for (x=0; x < 2; ++x)
                {
                    Equals();
                }

I know this is wrong, instead of x < 2, i don't know what it should be (loop until a non-duplicate is entered), and what needs to be passed to the Equals method? I am not sure of the syntax here.

Comment: Why don't you use dictionary. If require you can convert to array.

Comment: because that's outside of the scope of the project. Its for my first semester in C#.

Comment: first: please edit also in your question. second: did you put the overridden `Equals` in the `Job`-class? third: `Equals` compares 2 objects, in your case of type `Job`. So you have to call it like `bool res=myJob.Equals(otherJob)`.

Comment: You mention you get an error when you try to call the Equals method - if you plan to ask more questions on SO try to get used to specifying _which_ error. You'll get better and faster responses that way.

Comment: Tell your teacher she could do better with that `Equals` method... passing in a `null` or something that is not a `Job` will make that method fail miserably in runtime. "Out of the scope of the project" is no reason to hand out hideously implemented code.

Comment: I agree that she is handing out poorly designed code as well as limiting us to using outdated means to accomplish a simple task.

So, given my existing code, what is the best and easiest way to prevent a duplicate entry for the jobNum integer in my for loop?

Comment: Outdated means is not an issue. Learning the basics is important, you have no business dealing with dictionaries and more advanced structures and idioms if you can't handle the current assignment. Baby steps are the way to go, but, again, thats not reason to hand out improvable code.

Comment: I'm confused here, @inBetween.

I have had no issues in this class until this assignment. I have also updated my original post to show the entirety of the code I have so far.

I am a visual learner and seeing the syntax written out helps me to understand the logic as well.

Does the code that prevent duplicate entries go in the for loop, in the method called by the for loop, or elsewhere?

Comment: Post linked as [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340018/using-contains-on-a-property-in-a-list) contains most ways of checking if element is present in an array (except using `for`, but there are enough of questions about "foreach into for"). It that is not enough - try searching  https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+check+array+contains+by+property as operation you are looking for is "array/list **contains**".

Answer (score 2):

This is homework, so I'll only give you some pointers:

1. Don't hand in the array (`jobbies`) storing the jobs to `GetJobData`. This method should have only one concern: getting job data. Figuring out if the data has a duplicate `Id` is not it's concern.
2. Write a helper method that checks for duplicates. What does it need? It needs all previous jobs, how many there are, and the new job it needs to validate. The following signature looks about right:

   ```
   private static bool CheckIfNewJobIsValid(Job newJob,
                                            Job[] jobs,
                                            int jobsValidatedCount)
   ```

   What does this method have to do? Well, it only needs to loop through the first `jobsValidatedCount` jobs in `jobs` and check if `newJob` equals any of them. If it does, bail out returning `false`. If the loop finishes then you can return `true`, no match was found.
3. `jobsValidatedCount` doesn't need to be a new counter, maybe some other already existing variable in the code can give you that info already.

Good luck!

P.D. Because this was already handed down by your teacher, I'll fix up the `Equals` method just a little:

```
public override bool Equals(Object e)
{
    bool equal = false;
    Job temp = e as Job;

    if (Job != null && JobNumber == temp.JobNumber)
    {
        equal = true;
    }

    return equal;
}
```

P.D. As Alexei Levenkov points out in comments, using `Equals` ony for `JobNumber` comparisson seems a bad idea. Are any two jobs with the same `JobNumber` really equal regardless of the value of all other properties? That could be confusing to say the least. A better approach would be to directly check `JobNumber` inside `CheckIfNewJobIsValid` and not use `Equals` but I guess its use is due to academic reasons.

Comment: Side note: `Equals` that compares just half of the properties is awesome source of future confusion. Not sure what teacher is setting up students for - need something like "story of my assignment" blog post :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Very true, I'll point that out. I'm guessing part of the assigment is understanding `overriding` and the use of `Equals` although the example is not exactly teaching best practices in many aspects.